# Ubuntu 18.04LTS and Kyber Scheduler

Tags: scheduler

I am trying to enable kyber IO scheduler on Ubuntu Server 18.04LTS. This is the method I used to use on Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS.

**nano /etc/default/grub**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=y dm_mod.use_blk_mq=y"
```

**update-grub**

**nano /etc/udev/rules.d/60-schedulers.rules**

```
ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/rotational}=="1", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="kyber"
```

**reboot**

Does anyone know the correct way to set kyber as the IO scheduler on 18.04, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out blk_mq was not enabled in the kernel, so it couldn't use any of the multi queue schedulers.

Installing another Kernel fixed the issue.